# Default slsb-strict-max-pool size in Wildfly 10

Tags: ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

On wildfly 10 server startup we get slsb-strict-max-pool as 64

```
2017-08-24 12:51:09,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
2017-08-24 12:51:09,166 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
```

But when I execute below for jboss-cli then the `**max pool size is 20**` as shown in the below image

```
/host=master/server=server-one/subsystem=ejb3/strict-max-bean-instance-pool=slsb-strict-max-pool/:read-resource(recursive=false)
```

[image]

Exactly what is the default max pool size of ejb in Wildfly 10 ??

Answer (score 3):

The pool size is dynamic by default because it is derived from the worker thread-pool size ("derive-size" property). So in your case you have 4 CPU cores and get a pool size of 64.
The max-pool-size value is ignored in this case so what the wildfly interface is saying is the correct runtime value.

https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/10.1/subsystem/ejb3/strict-max-bean-instance-pool/index.html